# JSOUP Element.html("<th>test</th>") ignore th tags

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

I work on a html templating engine based on jsoup.
JSOUP ignore th and td flags if element is not inside table;

To deal with this, I change parser to :

```
    final Document docToWrite = Jsoup.parse(docToRead.outerHtml(),"", Parser.xmlParser());
```

But I didn't find any solution to fill an Element with html that contain a td or a th:

```
    element.html("<th>test</th>");
```

return only test, because JSOUP is cleaning html by removing unused tags

How can I solve this?

Thank you

Comment: where your element is taken from? what tag is it (element.tag())?

Answer (score 0):

If you element is 'th', then calling:

```
element.html("<th>test</th>") // th.innerHTML = "<th>test</th>"
```

should produce dirty html:

```
<th><th>test</th></th>
```

which is correctly cleared up by JSoup to:

```
<th>test</th> // th.innerHTML == "test"
```

To fill element with innerHTML == "<th>test</th>" your element has to be a <tr> tag.

```
// Given
String s = "<th>test</th>";
assert element.tag() == "tr";

// When
element.html(s);

// Then
assert element.html().equals(s);
```